# How do I detect that a fifo has been deleted in Python

Tags: python, linux, named-pipes, mkfifo

In Python, I can poll for incoming data on a fifo (created with the Linux `mkfifo` command) with:

```
reader = open(known_fifo_name,"r")
while True:
   data = reader.read(1)
   if data:
      process(data)
   else:
      time.sleep(0.1) #no data now, try later
```

But `read()` returns the empty string both when there is no data, and when the fifo has been deleted (by an external program with a `remove()` call).
Is there a way to tell that the fifo I am listening to no longer exists?

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with FIFO. Is known_fifo_name a variable(data structure) or file? or what is it exactly?

Comment: Also, if it returns an empty string.. can you do if data!= ""

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import os
try:
    os.stat(reader.fileno())
except OSError:
    # The FIFO has gone away
sleep(0.1)  # Wait for some more input
```